# onCreate|(Bundle) must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: android

I'm using a cusom dialog box in the mainActivity of my project... it was perfectly working, but, now i got an error message when i trying to use that class.

The error is like this:

```
The method onCreate(bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method
```

the code is giving below... anyone know the problem?? please help me...

```
package MainPRJ.Diary;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;




import android.R.string;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Contacts.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
//This means the baseline (MDPI) asset is 48x48 px, and the high density (HDPI) asset should be 1.5x the baseline at 72x72 px, and the x-high density (XHDPI) asset should be 2x the baseline at 96x96 px, and so on.

public class MainPRJ extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    EditText e1;
    ImageView ok,t5,t6;
    DBManager dbManager;
    Context cont=this;
    ArrayList<Object> arl=null;
    Boolean f;
    int flag=0;
    String str;
    settings st;
    boolean checkcontent;
    connectionDetector cd;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    static Integer c=3;

    /*ArrayList<Object> arrHint;
    Context context=this;
    ArrayList< Object> arPswd;*/





    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        st=new settings();

        t5=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.text5);
        t6=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.text6);
        e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ok=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login_ok);
        dbManager=new DBManager(this);

        cd = new connectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        checkcontent=dbManager.getavailability();
        if(checkcontent)
        {
            t5.setImageResource(R.drawable.userdetail);
            t6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            e1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ok.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            flag=1;

            //t5.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            t6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            e1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ok.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e1.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the password", 5000).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    arl=dbManager.retrievePswdAsArray();
                    if(e1.getText().toString().equals((String)arl.get(0)))
                    {
                    Intent i1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), first_page.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                    arl.clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Incorrect", 5000).show();
                }
                }

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (String)arl.get(0), 3000).show();
            }
        });



        t5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //checkcontent=dbManager.getavailability();
               //if(checkcontent)
                if(flag==1)
                {
                    //t5.setText("User Details");
                    Intent int3=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), userinfoshow.class);
                    startActivity(int3);

                   //t5.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent int2=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), user_information.class);
                    startActivity(int2);
                }
            }
        });
        t6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                arl= dbManager.retrievePswdAsArray();


                final String pass=(String)arl.get(0);
                arl.clear();
                arl=dbManager.retrieveHintAsArray();
                final String hint=(String)arl.get(0);
                arl.clear();
                final Dialog mdialog = new Dialog(MainPRJ.this);
                mdialog.setContentView(R.layout.forgot_pswd_dialog);
                mdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                mdialog.setTitle("Password Access");
                holder.OK = (Button) mdialog.findViewById(R.id.frgtOk);
                holder.CANCEL= (Button) mdialog.findViewById(R.id.frgtCancel);
                holder.HINT_ANS = (EditText) mdialog.findViewById(R.id.frgtHint);
                holder.CAUTION = (TextView) mdialog.findViewById(R.id.frgtCaution);
                mdialog.show();

                holder.OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(holder.HINT_ANS.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(hint))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hint+" "+pass, 3000).show();
                            if (isInternetPresent) 
                            {
                                ArrayList< Object> arrEmail= dbManager.retrieveDetailsAsArray();
                                String name=(String)arrEmail.get(0);
                                final String mail = (String) arrEmail.get(6);
                                final String content = "Hai "+name+"\n Your security password is : "+pass+"\n\n\n\n\n Regards...AuFriDis";

                                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try
                                        {

                                        sendMail(mail, content);
                                    }

                                    catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                    }
                                    }
                                });
                                t.start();

                            mdialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                showAlertDialog(MainPRJ.this, "No Internet Connection",
                                        "Password cannot be sent to mail address...", false);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            c--;
                            if(c>0)
                            {
                            holder.CAUTION.setText("Incorrect Hint Answer \n"+c+" more try...");
                            }
                            else if(c==0)
                            {

                                if (isInternetPresent) 
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your hint answer is send to mail address", 3000).show();
                                    ArrayList< Object> arrEmail= dbManager.retrieveDetailsAsArray();
                                    String name=(String)arrEmail.get(0);
                                    final String mail = (String) arrEmail.get(6);
                                    arrEmail.clear();
                                    arrEmail=dbManager.retrieveHintAsArray();
                                    String hint=(String)arrEmail.get(0);
                                    final String content = "Hai "+name+"\n Your security question is : Nickname of your childhood friend\n Your security answer is : "+hint+"\n\n\n\n\n Regards...AuFriDis";

                                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            try
                                            {

                                            sendMail(mail, content);
                                        }

                                        catch (Exception e) {
                                            // TODO: handle exception
                                        }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    t.start();
                                    c=3;

                                mdialog.dismiss();

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    showAlertDialog(MainPRJ.this, "No Internet Connection",
                                            "Security Answer cannot be sent to mail address...", false);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
                holder.HINT_ANS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        holder.CAUTION.setText("");
                    }
                });         
                holder.CANCEL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mdialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            }
        });


    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: custom dialog u say? so where is the code for that class for the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Your project's java version may be changed to 1.5 somehow. Try changing it to 1.6.

Go to
`Properties -> JDK Compiler -> Select "1.6" from the Compiler compliance level dropdown (Android only supports 1.5 and 1.6, it does not yet support 1.7)`

Comment: If someone's answer is helpful, please try accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The error reported refers to '**MainActivity**', where is it? You have posted code for the class **MainPRJ**.

Also (although not responsible for the error) package names should be in lower case, like:
com.yourname.yourproject.